# Removing all ï»¿ï»¿ type characters

Tags: php, special-characters

I have constant problems with data where odd characters like `ï»¿ï»¿` will show up in our database causing everything to break at some point down the line.  I need to get a system in place that only allows specific characters through and ignores all of these crazy things that can be pasted from Microsoft Office.  Is there something like this built in, or should I start from scratch?

Comment: The easiest solution may be to add a js handler to the frontend that forces pasted input to plain text. Not sure exactly how to implement but i know i have the option turned on in FCK/CK editor on a couple projects. By doing it on the client side the user knows what the formatting will look like which is good if some of those chars are something that matters.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is character encoding conflicts. Did you verify all charsets match,  database, charset of webpage used to add data, and while your at it the HTTP headers of accepted and responded charsets?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am no expert in character encoding, but was told about this specific problem and why your getting it. As stated in my comment above, you have to verify all your character sets match.

However, here is why your getting that specific set of characters:

> "That particular sequence of characters is the 3-byte UTF-8 code for
>   the [?] [unknown] character you see in Firefox. you get that when you
>   display a 1-byte Windows-1252 character as UTF-8 in a form, and then
>   submit it back to the database. The browser sends the 3-byte UTF-8
>   character in its place"

Understanding charsets is a challenge and I highly recommend you read more on this subject. Here is a good start: [Character Sets / Character Encoding Issues](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets)

Comment: More linking (and sucking up): http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove all such characters via e.g. `$text = preg_replace('@[^\d\w\s,.;:]@', '', $text);` where `[^\d\w\s,.;:]` is a set of characters to keep (\d\w\s means all digits, letters, and spaces). Amend the set with other characters you do want to keep.

However, that is the wrong approach. You should instead ensure that your entire application is using and processing UTF-8 from ground up, so that you can store and handle those characters correctly. Making an ASCII or ISO Latin site in this day and age is just weird and essentially causes data loss due to cutting out characters that people actually use...

Comment: I have a very limited understanding as to how encodings work... if I have my database store it in UTF 8, would I need to encode it from the browser?  If the browser isn't pasting the content in UTF-8 then the characters are already messed up, right ?

Comment: Right, it has to be UTF-8 from ground up. Store UTF-8 in the db, process UTF-8 in PHP, and have the HTML output set to UTF-8 and all forms submit in UTF-8. I usually have `enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8"` in my `<form>` tags for the latter part. In PHP you'd want to read up on probably http://php.net/mysql_set_charset

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 works with any characters from any language. UTF-8 is the 8bit encoding of the Unicode standard.